# MVC- How can I let my content page add an extra ContentPlaceHolder?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have  a content page inherited from master page.
There are two ContentPlaceHolder in master page.

The master page like:

```
<html>
<head runat="server">

    <title><asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" /></title>

</head>
<body>
        <div id="main">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server" />
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The content page like:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">

</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

</asp:Content>
```

My problem is when i add an extra ContentPlaceHolder in the master page like that:

```
<html>
<head runat="server">

    <title><asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" /></title>

</head>
<body>
        <div id="main">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server" />
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent2" runat="server" />

        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

the content page still are two `<asp:Content>` in it like:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">

</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

</asp:Content>
```

I have try refresh the content page and establish the project again but still are two `<asp:Content>` in the content page. Did I miss something? Can someone please give me help?

Comment: Have you tried manually adding the 3rd Content control in your content page?

Comment: you can just add them yourself into each view if you need to. The content pages don't have to implement every placeholder necessarily. The IDE won't do this for you, because it doesn't know in which views you might want to make use of it, nor does it know where in the view you'd want to place it. If you create a brand new view using the wizard, it will probably add it then as an empty placeholder, but it won't go back and add things to existing views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i know Visual Studio don't update your content pages if you add a new ContentPlaceHolder in your master Page.

You need to add to your page manually.
like this.
In Master Page if you added below:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="newcontentplaceholder" runat="server"> 
 </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

In content Page add

```
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="newcontentplaceholder" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
```